# Optimization of for loop in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I was asked on my apprenticeship following question:
Why query like:

```
FOR i in ( SELECT * FROM TABELKA) LOOP
```

is not efficient? How to change it to make it more efficient?

There is no further information added.

Comment: I was told that it is not efficient and i must change that query. I was thinking about using cursors instead of this loop and change select * into select col1, col2, etc

Comment: that's not what i meant. why do you have to loop for selecting all records in the table?

Comment: It's just an academic question. I got a task to say what is wrong with this query and how to make it work better.

Comment: IMO this is a poor question to be asked and symptomatic of academia's excessive focus on drawing conclusions from minimal data.  The query itself is fine, and without further information no more can be said about it.  "Further information" *might* include - how many rows in the table, how many columns, how many of those columns are actually used in later code, it this really a table or is it a view, what does the execution plan look like.

Comment: Agreed with Bob. The statement "x is not efficient" makes no sense because efficiency is a relative term. It assumes there is one method that is "most efficient" and therefore all other methods are deemed "not efficient" in comparison. This is simply not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect, all data at once, into a collection. Boom! One query and you have it all without looping.

```
SELECT *
BULK COLLECT INTO a_collection_type_variable
FROM a_table;
```

Comment: This is probably not good advice.  Oracle 10g+ will automatically bulk collect this type of loop.

Comment: unless you want to loop through 10 million rows...Bulk collect isn't always a replacement for an cursor loop.  With large sets, probably need a cursor + bulk collect with limit.